# Why page speed insights is taking field data from a different url if the original one contains a '?'

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have tested some pages which contains parameters "?" in PSI. As a result page speed insights is taking field data from a different url if the original one contains a '?'. Please refer the below snap.

[Page Speed Insight - Field data for diff. url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzUqi.png)

Trying to get to the bottom of whether it's still giving lab data for the right page but showing the incorrect URL under 'This URL'(Field data)...

Answer (score 1):

Crux field data normalizes the URL a bit. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/api/reference/rest/v1/records/queryRecord#urlnormalization

The lab report will still run on the exact url you give (and follow redirects).